# store UITextFields value somewhere for a short time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I have a `viewController` where people need to fill in some `textfields`. When people tap on the green spot they navigate to another view to make a little signature and then they come back.

[image]

The problem I'm having here is that when the user come back after that they entered their signature. My values from my textfields are gone.

Like you can see only the textfields with a * are obliged. I've tried putting those values in a `NSDictionary` and store them in `NSUserdefaults`. But when I don't fill up every textfield I get this error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: naam)'
```

What is the best way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these `methods` to use when `store temporary data` in `Temp Directory` and `retrieve` from it

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark Data Save

// need a path
- (NSString *)getArrayPath
{
  //NSString* path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
  return [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.dat"];
}

// save an array
- (void)saveVideoData:(NSMutableArray*)data
{
  [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:data toFile:[self getArrayPath]];
}

// get that array back
- (NSMutableArray *)loadSavedData
{
  return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self getArrayPath]];
}
```

Save values : For ex.

```
 //create array
 NSMutableArray *arrValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:txt1.text,txt2.text,txt3.text,nil];
 [self saveVideoData:arrValues];
```

Get Values : For ex.

```
 NSMutableArray *arrValues = [self loadSavedData];
```

By Add above methods in `another view controller` u can get `data values` `there` also.

Comment: This fixed my problem. And I think i'm gonna use this more often ! Good solution dude !

Answer (score 1):

> reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: naam)'

**Explanation :** You can't set `NULL` values in your `NSDictionary`.

**Answer :** When your `textField` value is `NULL` , try to store **"" (Empty Value)** in `NSDictionary`.

Perform Check like this :

```
if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""] || textField.text.length == 0)
{
     [yourDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"someKey"];
}
```

Comment: I still get this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: adres)'

Comment: @StefGeelen : Try to add one more condition to your If statement. Check my Code again. You have to check this for all the TextFields.

Comment: @StefGeelen: Also check with BreakPoints that , you are able to reach at this line `[yourDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"someKey"];` or not when your textField is Empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether that key exists or not as :

```
    NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([defs objectForKey:@"naam"]) // Here it is YES if the key naam exists else no
    {
       // Key naam does exists
       // set that value in textfield
    }
    else
    {
    // Key naam does not exist
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a singleton class.
2. Put your values in there (If the values are nil enter "" for that value)
3. Fetch the value once you come back to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are  trying to set NULL value in dictionary in that case you will get this error. So please try to use this one.And you should do like this for all text field

```
if (naamTextField.text.lenght == 0)
     [dic setValue:@"" forKey:@"NAAM"];
else
     [dic setValue:naamTextField.text forKey:@"NAAM"];
if (emailTextField.text.lenght == 0)
     [dic setValue:@"" forKey:@"EMAIL"];
else
     [dic setValue:emailTextField.text forKey:@"EMAIL"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Only store textfield that have values.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    if(textField.text.length > 0){
      [dictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"<somekey>"];

      NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      [defaults setObject:dictionary forKey:@"<defaultKey>"];
      [defaults synchronize];
   }
```

}

and in your viewDidAppear just load fetch the dictionary from the defaults and display it

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for your problem may be, just `pushing/presenting` `anotherViewController` over `yourViewController` then `pop/dismiss` `anotherViewController` as `yourViewController` was at root of `anotherViewController` thus it's still remain in it's previous state. With all field filled with the previous values.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you push/present yourviewController to other viewController and pop/dimiss that pushed Controller, normally the values in the textfield does not change untill you write something in ViewWillAppear...

This should not happen !! Generally